# lectura de archivos binarios y escritura por pantalla

Tags: java, archivo, binario

estoy intentando que mi programa guarde objetos en un archivo .dat y después lo muestre por pantalla, pero en lo segundo no soy capaz.Os muestro el codigo y vuelvo a añadir explicaciones:

```
package acserialible;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author a19alexnp
  */
public class Binary {

public static ArrayList<Product> createProducts() {
    int[] identifiers = {123, 456, 789, 235, 567};
    String[] descriptions = {"coffee", "milk", "rice", "salt", "cocoa"};
    double[] prices = {1.22, 1.05, 1, 1.25, 3.2};

    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product product;
    for (int i = 0; i < identifiers.length; i++) {
        product = new Product(identifiers[i], descriptions[i], (float) prices[i]);
        products.add(product);
    }
    return products;
}

public static void storeProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileOutputStream data = null;
    ObjectOutputStream tuberiaData = null;

    try {

        data = new FileOutputStream("products.dat");
        tuberiaData = new ObjectOutputStream(data);

        for (Product product : products) {
            tuberiaData.writeObject(product);
        }
        tuberiaData.close();
        data.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + error.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void readProducts() {
    FileInputStream datos = null;
    ObjectInputStream tuberiaDatos = null;
    

    try {
        datos = new FileInputStream("products.dat");
        tuberiaDatos = new ObjectInputStream(datos);
         Product p1 = null;
       
            p1= (Product) tuberiaDatos.readObject();
            System.out.println(p1);

        }
        tuberiaDatos.close();
        datos.close();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<Product> productsList = createProducts();
    System.out.println(productsList);
    try {
        storeProducts(productsList);
        readProducts();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException main: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo que contiene el main, estuve buscando soluciones pero encontré algunas que solo servian para leer un archivo binario el primer caracter. Creo que el fallo está dentro de la sentencia del while, ya que lo que hago con FileOutputStream y ObjectInputStream creo que está bien.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da?

Comment: no me imprime nada por pantalla

Comment: acabo de cambiar una parte del codigo, la del metodo readProducts , que es donde está el fallo, pero aun sigo sin conseguir que me imprima todos los objetos, me imprime solo uno

Comment: Tal como está en la pregunta el programa no compilaría, en readProducts o sobra una llave o te has comido el inicio de un bucle.

Comment: Por lo que veo, solo estás leyendo un objeto en `readProducts`. El metodo `readObject` lanzara un `EOFException` cuando llegue al final del archivo. Asi que para leer los objetos simplemente debes usar un `while(true) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void readProducts() {
    FileInputStream datos = null;
    ObjectInputStream tuberiaDatos = null;

    try {
        datos = new FileInputStream("products.dat");
        tuberiaDatos = new ObjectInputStream(datos);

        Product p1;
        while (datos.available() > 0) {
            p1 = (Product) tuberiaDatos.readObject();

            System.out.println(p1);
        }

        tuberiaDatos.close();
        datos.close();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

esta seria la respuesta

Comment: Agrega una explicación de tu código